# How to conceptually think about repeated sampling with instrumental variables?

Tags: distributions, sampling, instrumental-variables

Say I am using rainfall during a protest as an instrument for political participation on some outcome y. When thinking conceptually about the sampling distribution, what does this mean here?

Is it that, for whatever values of rainfall hit different regions, I hold fixed, and think of drawing errors for each place again, or is it thinking if we he gone back and started the day over, rainfall would have hit different places at different levels, and then thinking about this thought experiment again and again?